# Why won't this JAVA code work as expected?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

So, this seems fairly simple bit of code.But when I run this, it gives me strange output.
First, I store the number of elements of `queries[] Array` in `NumQ` variable.Then, I store the values of elements by looping from 0 to numQ-1.It works in any other case.

```
int numQ=sc.nextInt();
  String queries[]=new String[numQ];
    for(int i=0;i<numQ;i++){

        queries[i]=sc.nextLine();
    }
System.out.println(queries[0]);
System.out.println(queries[1]);
System.out.println(queries[2]);
```

In my case, inputs are-(note that it even doesn't ask for the value at index 2.numQ is 3)

[image]

And here is the output.

[image: Output of the code]

See, at `queries[0]`, it stores blank value(blue selection is blank).At `queries[ 1 ]`, it stores the first input(which was to be stored at index 0.And it stores the index 1 value at index 2 and so on.)

So what's the problem with my code.
Thanks in advance:-)

Comment: When using a combination of `nextInt` and `nextLine`, beware there is still content in the buffer (ie the new line) which needs to be processed.  Maybe use `nextLine` and use another `Scanner` on the result to get the `numQ`

Comment: I didn't notice it's a problem related with Scanners.And never saw that it's duplicate

Comment: If you type in 4 5 then press enter, it works.  It's picking up the enter value, blank, and putting it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `sc` is a Scanner Object. The method `nextInt()` scan only int part before newline. So you have to use `sc.nextLine()` to skip the newline

```
int numQ=sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();

String queries[]=new String[numQ];
for(int i=0;i<numQ;i++){
    queries[i]=sc.nextLine();
}
System.out.println(queries[0]);
System.out.println(queries[1]);
System.out.println(queries[2]);
```